# Does minifyEnabled true changes class names in Android Studio?

Tags: android, proguard

I have added `minifyEnabled true` but class names are still visible. I have not added any progaured keep rules too. Why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure that no classes were renamed? Proguard only obfuscates classes that are not referenced in AndroidManifets.xml or other XML files like layouts or themes.

Comment: If we do not have XML file for a class then only Proguard obfuscates - do you want to say this?

Comment: Yes and no, the XML file does not have to "belong" to the class. AndroidManifest e.g. contains references to multiple classes (all activities, receiver, ...).

Comment: Why my Activities and Fragments names are there even after applying proguard? - any reason

Comment: Because every Activity class is mentioned in `AndroidManifest.xml` and Proguard does not modify XML files, thus it can not rename those classes. If you want to rename all classes you have to buy one of the commercial Android obfuscators that support this.